# Merging NetCDF files

Tags: python, netcdf4

I have **netcdf** files downloaded between 2010 and 2021. I have tried to combine them using the code below, but the time column starts with `01.01.1900 00:00` instead starting with `01.01.2010 00:00`. How can I fix this?

```
import netCDF4
import numpy
import xarray

ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('e.*.nc',combine = 'by_coords', concat_dim="time")

ds.to_netcdf('eras_bir.nc')
```

Comment: Can you share some of the files to try your code? xarray for me has seemed to work...

Comment: I don't know how to share files. But I tried with cdo and it was partially successful.